# Question regarding field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For any positive integer $k$ and prime $p$ find necessary and sufficient condition for $Z_p[\sqrt k] =\{a+b{\sqrt k}\mid a,b \in Z_p\}$ to be a field. Any help would be appreciated. While I am getting for any prime $p$ and $k.$ I don't think it's right. Thanks.

Comment: You're correct: your conjecture is wrong. For example, with $p=2$ and $k=3$ it is not a field. Maybe if you said something about how you got to your guess, we can help.

Comment: I know. This was the example

Comment: How are operations defined in $\mathbb Z_p[\sqrt k]$ ? What does $\sqrt k$ mean in the context of $\mathbb Z_p$ ?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the correct interpretation of $\mathbb Z_p[\sqrt k]$ is
$
\mathbb Z_p[X]/(X^2-k)
$.

With this interpretation, we have $\mathbb Z_p[\sqrt k]$ is a field iff $k$ is not a square mod $p$, because when $k \equiv a^2 \bmod p$ we have
$$
\mathbb Z_p[X]/(X^2-k)
=
\mathbb Z_p[X]/(X^2-a^2)
\cong
\mathbb Z_p[X]/(X-a)
\times
\mathbb Z_p[X]/(X+a)
\cong
\mathbb Z_p \times \mathbb Z_p
$$